# dyGraphs Second Y Axis not being displayed when using a variable as 'y2'

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have the following code to display a graph with two axes. The data is of the form:
`Date, Value1, Value2`

```
var sg = new Dygraph(document.getElemantById("div"),
lGraphData,
{
    labels: ['Date', string1, string2],
    legend: 'always',
    series: {
        string2 : {
            axis: 'y2'
        }
    },
    ylabel: string1,
    y2label: string2
});
```

Instead of displaying the `y2axis`, both series appear on the graph and only `y axis` showing.
If I replace `string2` (a variable string) with `Y2` in the above code, both axes appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic JavaScript issue. When string2 appears as a key in an object literal, it means the string "string2", not the value of the string2 variable. You need to create an options object and fill it out in pieces, like so:

```
var opts = {
    labels: ['Date', string1, string2],
    legend: 'always',
    series: {},
    ylabel: string1,
    y2label: string2
};
opts.series[string2] = { axis: 'y2' };

var sg = new Dygraph(document.getElemantById("div"), lGraphData, opts);
```