# Dygraph: reference series by variables

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

When i try to update an option of a specific Serie 'S1' like the following code, it works fine:

```
g.updateOptions({
  'S1':{ fillAlpha:0.15 }
});
```

But when i specify the serie name with a variable, it doesn't work:

```
var Label_s='S1';
g.updateOptions({
  Label_s:{ fillAlpha:0.15 }
});
```

the code simply doesn't make any changes and the browser-console also shows me no errors.
My question is : how can i change an option of a serie, when the serie's name is unknown? It is a variable specified later by the user.

Any idea why the code above is not working? Thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [dyGraphs Second Y Axis not being displayed when using a variable as 'y2'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455062/dygraphs-second-y-axis-not-being-displayed-when-using-a-variable-as-y2)

Comment: Label_s is treated as a string literal inside `{...}`. You need to set it via something like `var options = {}; options[Label_s] = { fillAlpha: 0.15 };`.

Comment: Now you can write it shorter as `{ [Label_s]:{ fillAlpha:0.15 } }` (note the `[]` around variable's name).