# Setting options object key: value pairs to achieve dynamic plotting w/2nd y-axis

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I need to add a 2nd axis to my plots.  Often we plot, say, a temperature (300-700 deg F) against a tank level (say, 15,000 - 30,000 gallons), so two axes for two different scales would be great.

Now, I did read the instructions and examples & I understand how to set up the 2nd axes.  It all works GREAT if it's static (i.e. I hard-code the tag name/column name).  If it's dynamic, I can't do it.  Because the user selects from a Jquery autocomplete of 1000+ tags, it needs to work for any tag.  I read about the 'options object'; it appears that is what I need to use, but my code breaks when I attempt to follow [dyGraphs Second Y Axis not being displayed when using a variable as 'y2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455062/dygraphs-second-y-axis-not-being-displayed-when-using-a-variable-as-y2) which is the closest code I could find.

This code works (using literals), but I don't know how to change the contents of 'LE505 R505 Receiver Level' in its two occurrences.  I need to set it to the value of the Javascript variable 'tagselected2'.

I should add, I am not sure if I need to scape the quotes with \'

'rarray' is loaded from an ASP page via XMLHTTP requesst.  ASP page queries the mySQL server and the returned results contain the time series data from RSVIEW32 (industrial automation datalogs from a chemical plant).  That part works great & I can plot up to 3 tags selected by the user, but I can't get the 2nd y-axis to work because I'm missing something.  I'd like to learn more about setting options string dynamically for other enhancements too.

```
 var opts =  {            

        series : { 'LE505 R505 Receiver Level': {axis: 'y2'} },
        axes: {
          'LE505 R505 Receiver Level': {
            // set axis-related properties here
            labelsKMB: true
          }
        },
            underlayCallback: drawLines,
            labelsDiv: document.getElementById('status'),
            labelsSeparateLines: true,
            legend: 'always',
            colors: ["rgb(51,204,204)",
                     "rgb(255,100,100)",
                     "#00DD55",
                     "rgba(50,50,200,0.4)"],
            width: $(window).innerWidth()-30,
            height: $(window).innerHeight()-140,
            title: tagselected,
            xlabel: 'Time and Date',
            ylabel: tagselected,
            axisLineColor: 'white'
            // drawXGrid: false
          };
          // opts.series[string2] = { axis: 'y2' };

           g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("demodiv"),rarray,opts);
```

I tried this code (doesn't work).  I didn't even attempt to set it to the variable, but was just trying to set the literal text string.

```
 var opts =  {

        series : string1,
        axes: string2,
            underlayCallback: drawLines,
            labelsDiv: document.getElementById('status'),
            labelsSeparateLines: true,
            legend: 'always',
            colors: ["rgb(51,204,204)",
                     "rgb(255,100,100)",
                     "#00DD55",
                     "rgba(50,50,200,0.4)"],
            width: $(window).innerWidth()-30,
            height: $(window).innerHeight()-140,
            title: tagselected,
            xlabel: 'Time and Date',
            ylabel: tagselected,
            axisLineColor: 'white'
            // drawXGrid: false
          };
           opts.series[string1] = { 'LE505 R505 Receiver Level': {axis: 'y2'} };
           opts.series[string2] = { 'LE505 R505 Receiver Level': { labelsKMB: true } };

           g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("demodiv"),rarray,opts);

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore my previous question, I now realize I had a syntax issue & fixed it.  I did not read your example thoroughly.  Below example works & plots on a 2nd axis based upon whether user checks a checkbox

The only other follow-on I had, is where/whether there is a reference you recommend on setting key: value pairs and learning Javascript better.

```
           var opts =  {

          series : { },

        axes: { },
            underlayCallback: drawLines,
            labelsDiv: document.getElementById('status'),
            labelsSeparateLines: true,
            legend: 'always',
            colors: ["rgb(51,204,204)",
                     "rgb(255,100,100)",
                     "#00DD55",
                     "rgba(50,50,200,0.4)"],
            width: $(window).innerWidth()-30,
            height: $(window).innerHeight()-140,
            title: tagselected,
            xlabel: 'Time and Date',
            ylabel: tagselected,
            axisLineColor: 'white'
            // drawXGrid: false
          };


           if (document.getElementById('tag2_2nd_axis').checked) {
               //alert("checked");
              opts.series[tagselected2] = {axis: 'y2'};
              opts.axes[tagselected2] = { labelsKBM: true};
           } else {
               //alert("Dual axes NOT checked");
           }
```